# Asterisk, keys don't work on background command,just after background

Tags: asterisk

```
[out]
exten=>_X.,1,Answer()
exten=>_X.,n,Background(hello)
exten=>_X.,n,WaitExten(5)

exten=>1,1,Goto(check,s,1)
```

Audio menu are playing, but when I press 1, sound stop and after few second check command run. How to quickly respond to a user request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing begginer error which described in almost any asterisk book for beginer.

I recommend you read "Asterisk The Future of Telephony" by O'Relly.

This exact error is simple:

- in your dialplan you have extension **_X.**, which mean "any number starting with digit.
- you ask asterisk waitfor extension selected in this context.
- you are pressing digit, but acordinly to context you may want enter 1111(also fit you context). So asterisk wait upto TIMEOUT(digits) until you enter next digit.
- your timeout is 5 second, so it go ext 1 in 5 second.

> [Syntax]
>
> BackGround(filename1[&filename2[&...]][,options[,langoverride[,context]]])

You can use other context for matching.

Comment: And nevertheless how to get rid of this problem, if I want to enter 1 after calling to number 111?

Comment: Read book, Victoria. Why you want me write you same info? It is TYPICAL dialplan, described everywhere. Or read how it done in FREEPBX dialplan.

Comment: O'Rellys "Asterisk the future of telephony", page 127.